# How to add Oracle Apex user to Group?

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using Oracle Apex 4.2

I have a code for creating APEX users programmatically,
and for that I use package
`wwv_flow_fnd_user_api.create_fnd_user`.

But I can't find any function for adding user to group.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind,

There is a parameter p_group_ids
in wwv_flow_fnd_user_api.create_fnd_user
which is used to add user in groups